# OpenGL geometry shader 2d rectangle extrusion has weird angles

Tags: opengl, shaders, geometry-shader

I have a geometry shader that extrudes lines to rectangles in 2d (by outputting triangle strips). When the lines are not parallel to the X or Y axis, I'm getting parallelograms instead. Also, when the line is parallel to the X axis, it appears thinner.

Here's what my result looks like, drawing 4 lines at different angles:
[image: Here's what my result looks like, drawing 4 lines at different angles]

Here's the geometry shader:

```
#version 150 core

layout(lines) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;
in vec3 Color[];
smooth out vec3 FColor;

void main() {
  vec3 g1 = gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz;
  vec3 g2 = gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz;
  vec3 v1 = normalize(g1 - g2) * 0.1;
  vec3 v2 = normalize(g2 - g1) * 0.1;

  FColor = Color[0];
  gl_Position = vec4(-v2.y + g1.x, v2.x + g1.y, 0.0, 1.0);
  EmitVertex();

  FColor = Color[0];
  gl_Position = vec4(v1.y + g2.x, -v1.x + g2.y, 0.0, 1.0);
  EmitVertex();

  FColor = Color[0];
  gl_Position = vec4(v2.y + g1.x, -v2.x + g1.y, 0.0, 1.0);
  EmitVertex();

  FColor = Color[0];
  gl_Position = vec4(-v1.y + g2.x, v1.x + g2.y, 0.0, 1.0);
  EmitVertex();

  EndPrimitive();
}
```

To test out the calculation, I ran the same set of vertices through the same calculation in GLM, took the results times 10.0 and plotted them using a web tool. Here's what I got:
[image: Here's what I got from the web plotter]

So it looks to me like the basic calculation is correct. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I am the world's biggest moron. My window is 800x600. That means that the X-axis from -1 to 1 is 800 pixels and the Y-axis from -1 to 1 is 600 pixels. If I use a square window, everything is... square.

Comment: Or you can scale things so that the Y-axis is -0.75 to 0.75 for example.